# Hyperledger data storage

Tags: hyperledger

I was trying to write a chaincode that would add ledgers uploaded by other members of the blockchain though couldnt find much information on how the hyperledger stores data. Can the data have different columns with one common column name? Also when the data is stored in the central ledger, how can i look for a particular string across a column ? 
I am new to hyperledger, so help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyperledger uses a NoSQL DB in the backend for storage of data (transactional info). Every transaction is identified by a unique txn id and the relevant info is encrypted, then mapped to this id and stored in the DB.

Now if you want to add the values in separate ledgers, you need to have the private key to decrypt those values. This wouldn't make sense as then how will companies ensure their ledgers are private and protected.

Now if you want to query all txn in the same ledger, you must keep the txn id with you which you will pass to the NoSQL DB as keys. The DB will return all the relevant information about the transaction to you.

Hope that clarifies a few things. Have a look at their documentation that uses [CouchDB](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#using-couchdb) in a clustered setup and LevelDB in a single node setup.